# What's the best way to temporarily store the values in swift to send them to a http post request at the end?

Tags: swift, forms, survey

I am building a form/survey that probably has 2 or 3 view controllers
what's the best way to temporarily store the values to send them to a http post request at the end?
NSUserDefaults? Memory (Array or Dictionaries or Strings)?

Thank you!

Comment: Avoid writing to disk if you don't need to - so, avoid using UserDefaults if possible. Just use normal variables, properties, etc that you can pass from one controller to the other.

Comment: If this is sensitive information you should always use the KeyChain, but for most things you can just use variables in memory. If you run into troubles of accessing the variables from all the different view controllers, you can just use static variables, or create a singleton class to hold the variables.

Comment: That's what I thought :-) TY @matt.writes.code I will try later to build a singleton class.. Now I create the outlet(s) for the text field and when creating the var I get an error -> `var cVar: NSString = cText.text` -> /Cannot use instance member 'cText' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available. Should I create the var on next VC?

Comment: For building a singleton this blog post is helpful: https://www.codefellows.org/blog/singletons-and-swift/

Comment: This other error you are getting is unclear to me, but this is the wrong place to ask about it because it's a separate issue. If I had to guess, you need to change it to var cVar: String? and then assign the value within a function where cText has a value. You can't get the value of a textfield before the UI has loaded.

Comment: Post your code in the question for context of the error.

Comment: All ok now. I have an array and I'm inserting into it all text field values :-)